# CakePHP 3 is trying to load a controller when accessing Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I just transferred a site from XAMPP to a live test site, and immediately encountered a problem - while the .css works, the site itself seems to try to load a controller instead of the actual Javascript file using

```
<?= $this->Html->script('jQuery-3.2.1.min.js'); ?>
```

What particular reasons would be causing this? I'm not really sure how to try to track this down.

All JS files are in webroot/js - I've tried to load from /js/ and js/ to the same effect, it acts like it's trying to load a normal component.

Strangely, I am getting

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery

Comment: where is jQuery-3.2.1.min.js?

Comment: I updated the question in response - my bad for not including.

Comment: Check the file/folder permissions

Comment: Folder permissions are 0775 and file permissions are 0664

Comment: Compare with the css folder/files

Comment: I found the problem, and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel rather stupid now. It was failing to work due to a capitalization mistake.